# Teamcity and Unit Testing Windows Store apps

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8.1, continuous-integration, win-universal-app, teamcity

I've been struggling to make Teamcity 9 compile and run Unit Tests for my Visual Studio solution.

I have a **Windows Phone 8.1** (WinRT, not silverlight) project and a "MyProject.Common.dll" portable class library with common functionality.

I created a "**Windows Phone Unit Test App**" project. If i run it from VS, it runs on the emulator and runs my unit tests. All is Ok.

If i want to run the unit tests from a **console** i use this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe MyProject.Tests_1.0.0.1_x86.appx /InIsolation /settings:RunOnEmu.runsettings"
```

It works. It launches the emulator, deploys the appx and run unit tests.

**Now the problem**: using Teamcity 9, i configure a command line build step runner using the same command , and i get this error:

> Error: Could not start test run for the tests for Windows Phone app:
>   Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from a service or non
>   interactive process. Please run unit tests from an interactive
>   process..

Is there a way to bypass this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, i made a custom script to launch `vstest.console.exe` and run the unit test appx and then another Build Step to load the tests results into TeamCity.

Comment: Hi, @Herno I've run into the same problem as you and the way I tried to solve it was running a custom powershell script but I still get the exception you mentioned. Could you please add some more info on how you solved this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I programmed a small C# program to launch the console. I could not bypass the error. If you want the source code i can share it, let me know

Comment: Aha, I understand now. That was what I was thinking of doing next. It would be a nice idea if you could post the code on github or as a gist so that if anybody else runs into this issue they could fix it faster. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to bypass that - run build agent as executable and not as a service. You can achieve that by removing TeamCity service:

```
service.stop.bat
service.uninstall.bat
```

(all .bat files are in bin folder of TeamCity build agent)

Then create new .bat file to start the build agent as an executable:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\bin\agent.bat start
```

And placing shortcut to this file into startup folder in `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` and setting up automatic logon as described [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/fl/auto-logon-windows-8.htm). That way build agent will start automatically after reboot.

I found this solution [here](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20151018-RunningWindowsStoreTestsInTeamCity.html) with some other common problems and solutions regarding Windows Store tests.

Answer (score 1):

Change Jenkins configuration for the needed slave. Within the option "Launch Method" now it's probably "Let Jenkins control this slave as a windows service", but you need "JLNP" (Java Network Launch Protocol):

[image]

Comment: I'm using Teamcity, not jenkins